# How to cancel warning "Allow access to the following application from this website”- Java

Tags: java, applet, security-warning

How can I cancel this security warning?

Information about this warning: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javascript_applet.xml

Comment: It's better to stop trying to use applets altogether. The technology has been dead for years and support from them is being removed from browsers.

Comment: Sorry but I can't change this technology right now. It's has a lot of problems @@

Comment: Well, just warning you that you're working with obsolete technology which *may stop working permanently at any time*.

Comment: *"How can I cancel this security warning?"* Click the cancel / no button on the dialog that appears when you go to run the applet. To allow the developer to remove that dialog would be a huge security hole. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).